# Django ORM DateTimeField ExpressionWrapper QuerySet annotation

Tags: django, django-orm

According to the Django documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations

I can do date calculations using ExpressionWrapper. I tried to use it like this:

```
    sprints = Sprint.objects.annotate(
        duration=models.Case(
            models.When(
                Q(started__isnull=False) &
                Q(done__isnull=False),
                then=models.Value(
                    models.ExpressionWrapper(
                        (models.F('done') - models.F('started')),
                        output_field=models.DateTimeField()
                    ))
            ),
            models.When(
                Q(started__isnull=False) &
                Q(done__isnull=True),
                then=models.Value(
                    models.ExpressionWrapper(
                        (Now() - models.F('started')),
                        output_field=models.DateTimeField(),
                    ))
            ),
            output_field=models.DateTimeField()
        )).values_list('name',
                       'planned',
                       'started',
                       'done',
                       'duration')
```

But I get an error from pytz trying to do auto-localisation on the ExpressionWrapper:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/phirt/local/venv/core3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/phirt/local/venv/core3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/phirt/local/venv/core3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/phirt/local/venv/core3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/phirt/local/venv/core3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 103, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/phirt/local/venv/core3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 483, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/phirt/local/venv/core3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 443, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/phirt/local/venv/core3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/phirt/src/core3/src/backend/portal/views/api/transformation.py", line 766, in get_sprint_data_csv
    for sprint in sprints:
  File "/home/phirt/local/venv/core3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 272, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/phirt/local/venv/core3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1179, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/phirt/local/venv/core3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1011, in apply_converters
    value = converter(value, expression, connection)
  File "/home/phirt/local/venv/core3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/operations.py", line 247, in convert_datetimefield_value
    value = timezone.make_aware(value, self.connection.timezone)
  File "/home/phirt/local/venv/core3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/timezone.py", line 269, in make_aware
    return timezone.localize(value, is_dst=is_dst)
  File "/home/phirt/local/venv/core3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytz/__init__.py", line 226, in localize
    if dt.tzinfo is not None:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'
```

And indeed the `dt` parameter passed to `localize` in pytz is a string, and it's exactly my ExpressionWrapper expression: `ExpressionWrapper(F(done) - F(started))`

How can I make this work?

Edit: Here is the sprint model:

```
class Sprint(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    planned = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    started = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    done = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='State')
    start_planned = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True,
                                         verbose_name='Start Planned')
    start_latest = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True,
                                        verbose_name='Start Latest')
    enforce_start = models.BooleanField(default=False,
                                        verbose_name='Enforce Start')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]
        verbose_name = "Sprint"

    def __str__(self):
        return f'<Sprint name="{self.name}">'
```

Comment: Can you pls add the `Sprint` model?

Comment: I've edited the question to include the model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made it work by changing the query annotation to the following:

```
    sprints = Sprint.objects.annotate(
        duration=models.Case(
            models.When(
                Q(started__isnull=False) &
                Q(done__isnull=False),
                then=(models.F('done') - models.F('started')),
            ),
            models.When(
                Q(started__isnull=False) &
                Q(done__isnull=True),
                then=(Now() - models.F('started')),
            ),
            output_field=models.DurationField()
        )).values_list('name',
                       'planned',
                       'started',
                       'done',
                       'duration')
```

Comment: Such a unique scenario, however by chance your question (and answer) helped me today, thank you sir!

Comment: @Patrick I'm doing something really similar and getting this error - `CASE types interval and integer cannot be matched`. Did you face it at any time? Seems like the origin of this error is that for the first 'if' it multiplies the days subtraction by  `interval 1days`  which is like casting I guess, but not to the other 'if'.

Comment: @user2880391 You seem to be using different types than I (interval instead of datetime). Try to cast your values to a common type, either both integers, both intervals, or both datetimes.